# Calculating width as percentage minus margin with LESS CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I use the Twitter Bootstrap grid system in my CMS app.

When users built a page, they can add any number of columns to a row. Consider this row:

```
<div class="span9 row">
    <div class="span5">span5</div>
    <div class="span4">span4</div>
</div>
```

What I want to do, is add a feature where users can set a row to equally distribute its width among the columns within.

So the `span5` and `span4` classes will be overridden. This would essentially behave like a table row, but I think it's hacky to make the row `display: table-row`, and it would probably ruin the responsive features of the TwBootstrap grid.

What I would like to avoid, is to define each combination of width as such:

```
<div class="span9 row shared child-count-2">
    <div class="span5">span5</div>
    <div class="span4">span4</div>
</div>
```

And in CSS:

```
.row.span9.shared.child-count-2 > div {
    width: 340px;
}
```

Since I'm already using LESS for CSS, I thought there might be a handy calculation that can make this work.

The problem is that specifying 50% width doesn't take into account the `20px` of `margin-left`. So I need to take the width of the row, minus 20px for each column. And then divide the remaining width with the number of columns.

Also, I would like to avoid using JavaScript. I don't like rendering 99% of a view, and then doing adjustments in script. If script execution gets a tiny delay users will see the layout flickering around. Not good.

**So, is there any way to do this from LESS/CSS?**

Answer (score 0):

You can achive that using LESS. With LESS you can use evaluation of JavaScript expressions wrapping them into back-ticks:

```
@var: `"hello".toUpperCase() + '!'`;
```

So you can use also things like `document.getElementById('myId').width` to get the width of an element and so on.. Check here [lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org/) and go to "JavaScript Evaluation" section.

If you need more help, just ask! :)

Comment: As far as I can see, the script will be evaluated at compile time. Since i pre-compile all my `less` files ``"hello".toUpperCase() + '!'`` end up saying `"HELLO!"` - and script for calculating the width will fail since e.g. `document` is `undefined` at compile time.

Comment: I think that there is no other ways to do what you want! The `row` width is calculated when the `div` element is rendered into the document. The only way to get it's width is at runtime, when the `row` element is ready. You should not compile your LESS or add a line of Javascript and CSS at the end of your HTML body, but, as you said in your question, for slower connections, the script execution gets a tiny delay and users'll see the layout flickering. My suggestion is to try those JavaScript methods and measure the page load speed, make some optimizations and evaluate delay's pros and cons!

Comment: I think I'll create a more "absolute" LESS script that compiles into specific width for each combination. A little more work, but a better solution IMHO.